# How can any proof of Gödel's incompleteness theorem be accepted considering systems of mathematics themselves are incomplete?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, incompleteness

I believe there are at least several proofs of Gödel's incompleteness theorem. Nagel and Newman wrote a book (1958) that presents one in particular.

But considering the theorem itself exposes inherent limitations of **every** formal axiomatic system, how can we paradoxically use such systems to prove the theorem of incompleteness?

Comment: The incompleteness theorem doesn't show that *no* true theorem has a proof.  Just that some don't.  The incompleteness theorem itself, clearly, isn't one of them.

Comment: I'll keep mind the expression “there are at least several”.

Comment: Seeing how your pot is not suitable for making fried eggs, how can any food be eaten?

Comment: @mjqxxxx so then I'll further ask does the chosen proof have to have some particular element above its primary goal that qualifies it as a *valid* proof?

Comment: @AsafKaragila point taken :) . But then mathematics is not a culinary endeavor.

Comment: The incompleteness theorem states that there are claims that are impossible to prove, not that there are no claims that can be proven.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I seem to remember that Gödel's theorems show that an axiomatic system equivalent to Peanos axioms are incomplete.

Comment: @limeeattack That is incorrect - Godel's theorems apply to any system having a couple basic properties. PA has these properties, but so do vastly stronger systems.

Comment: @Noah Schweber thank you for clearing that up. I might have learned it in connection to Brouwer's intuitionism, hence PA.

Comment: To the OP: Why should **knowing that there are questions a system *can't* answer** suggest that we should worry that **it's wrong about the questions it *does* answer**? They are simply different issues.

Comment: There is no paradox here. You are misunderstanding the technical meaning of the word "complete" in this context.  A formal system can be **sound** (i.e., incapable of proving false statements) without being **complete** (i..e., capable of proving all true statements).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: "at least several" made me smile too  $\ddot{\smile}$.

Answer (score 3):

The comments have already addressed this, but let me try to move this question off the "unanswered" list.

You write:

> But considering the theorem itself exposes inherent limitations of every formal axiomatic system, how can we paradoxically use such systems to prove the theorem of incompleteness?

I think you're treating all "inherent limitations" as being the same sort of thing, but they're not. There's nothing paradoxical going on here: the limits imposed by the incompleteness theorem do not say that we cannot trust the things a theory *does* prove, merely that we can't *expect* the theory to prove or disprove everything. That is, the existence of **gaps** has nothing to do with the existence of **errors**.

So there's nothing paradoxical going on here. Or rather, if you think there is, the onus is on *you* to draw the connection.

---

Of course, I'm not disagreeing that Godel's theorem - not its precise content, but rather then general realization that *logic is weird* - might reasonably cause us to be more skeptical of the axiomatic theories we use in general. So perhaps now, whenever we have a proof of a statement $p$ in a theory $T$ which is at all complicated, we might assert "$p$ is true *assuming* $T$ is correct" rather than "$p$ is true." But this resulting skepticism is no more directed towards the incompleteness theorem than it is towards all other theorems. There's no paradox here.